# How to read specific data from JSON file in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, json, file, object

I have a json file like this

```
{
  "user": {
    "age": 23,
    "firstName": "somebody"
    "height": "175"
    "weight": "75"
    "gender": "male"
  }
}
```

I also have a file index.js, in which I'm  loading the file with

```
let profileData = "./profile.json";
$.getJSON(profile,processProfileData);
```

In the same file, I have a function

```
function processProfileData(data){
    let profileName = document.getElementById('firstName');
    profileName.innerHTML = data.firstName;
}
```

All i want to do, is to show only the "firstName" in my index.html file, in a container. My code is like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div id="displayName"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(I have inserted in scripts in the header all necessairy src's to run bootstrap and apex charts)

Comment: Your json consists of an object with a single key of `user`, that references a nested object.  You're ignoring that nesting

Comment: Also a simple `console.log(data)` in that method would have shown you want it consists of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to reference the 'user' property that the data is nested in

```
function processProfileData(data){
    let profileName = document.getElementById('firstName');
    profileName.innerHTML = data.user.firstName;
}
```

And double check that you're grabbing the right HTML element.  In your example your  looking for an element with an id of "firstName", but in your html example it's called "displayName"